# Visual Studio keeps showing this message "please wait for an editor command to finish"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

My projects on Visual Studio 2019 were working fine. There was an auto-update and since then, I keep getting this annoying message:

> Please wait for an editor command to finish.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Happening to me too

Comment: I have the same problem... Still no fix

Comment: Just had the same issue; couldn't do anything while this message was still showing... Only escaped from it by closing Visual Studio and opening it again

Comment: 2022 Visual Studio - Happening to me also. Deleted the .vs file without success. It seems to happen a lot more when editing data files, like a JSON file. Just moving the cursor triggers a 30-second delay. Sometimes hours will pass without the issue. Other times you can't make a single change.

Answer (score 22):

I have fixed that problem by deleting `.vs` folder from project.

**update**

Some times `.vs`  may be hidden in solution folder make it visible from `folder option`

Answer (score 8):

Like as Akbar Asghari said, just delete .vs folder from project (located in the root solution, this folder is system hidden).

- Close the VS or kill the task.
- Delete the folder .vs
- Reopen solution and be happy.

Comment: Did not work for me - but I think I've got too many extensions, potentially conflicting with each other...

Answer (score 2):

Version: Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.3.6)

I tried the provided solution of deleting the .vs folder from the project without success. However, my problem seemed to go away when "Automatic brace-completion" was disabled.

Note: My problem was specific to editing a small JSON file. Maybe this will help others have an idea what to look for.

[image: Tools->Options->Disable Automatic brace completion]

Answer (score 1):

When I updated and added some more Rapid XAML extension in VS 2019 I started to get this message. So I deleted these extensions and it solved the problem but I also deleted the .vs folder in the solution I was working in. However this was happening in all the solutions so I think it was the extensions that was causing the issue.

Comment: Do you know if it was a specific extension, or if it was the number running/consuming memory at once?

Answer (score 1):

Spent hours looking for different options.
Looks like the error is caused by automated Code analysis.
Resolved by disabling code analysis for active document (see screenshot below).

[image: Visual Studio 2022 –> tools –> options:]

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue but the other methods did not work.

I have activated **GitHub Copilot** lately. A while it worked flawlessly (I guess Copilot was watching during the first period of time). Then, the already included AI of VS2022 - namely **ItelliCode** - and Github were active at the same time and caused crashes.

When I **disabled either** IntelliCode or Copilot, I had no more crashes.

To disable **IntelliCode** you can go to **Tools->Options->IntelliCode** and disable **"C# suggestions"**.

Or disable **Copilot**: **Tools->Options->GitHub->Copilot** and set **"Enable Globally"** to false.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and even after doing what Akbar Asghari said, it didn't work. Then I reset the Keyboard Shortcuts of VS22 Mac to default i.e. Visual Studio for Mac and it resolved the issue. I had set it to VSC Keybindings earlier.

[Link to Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2zCo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After unchecking the box `Auto cancel long running auxiliary operations on typing` in `Tools>Options>Text Editor>Advanced` the message box does not appear anymore.
I was able to resume working normally after doing so and VS behaved normally for all the session after that.